# jQuery Cookies not being set in Safari and IE

Tags: jquery, cookies

Im using the jquery.cookie plugin to save my application data like this:

```
$.cookie('cookieTest', 'appDataHere', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
alert( $.cookie("cookieTest") );
```

But for some reason the above outputs "undefined" in Safari and IE..

Any ideas?

Works fine in FF and Chrome..

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on a server?

Comment: I've got the same problem. Cookies not regestering in IE. I'm running a local server (xampp).